# Are showers any real use?

Tags: oxygen-not-included

In Oxygen Not Included I don't really see the benefit of showers. They use up a lot of space and water and most of the dupes are grimy most of the time anyway. I don't see any penalty for being grimy. In fact, the time showering seems wasted. Can anyone give me a hard numerical justification for building showers?

Comment: In my experience, there is no any real use of showers in all updates. Maybe in later one.

Comment: Wiki says they are currently of no real use, https://oxygennotincluded.gamepedia.com/Shower

Comment: @DavidYell I don't play this game but that link makes it sound like showers do pose a use since they help "prevent the spread of Diseases by allowing Duplicants to wash all the Germs off".

Comment: @Wipqozn Did you read the tips section?

Comment: @DavidYell I totally missed that, thanks! I'd strongly encourage you to post that as an answer instead of a comment then, and I'd include an explanation about why preventing the spread of disease currently doesn't matter.

Comment: Well other discussion around the issue seems to non-conclusive. As the game is early access, the answer to this question might change over time.

Comment: @DavidYell - The article is out of date now with the Expressive Update. My dupes had food poisoning and diarrhea, which resolved quicker after implementing showers.

Answer (score 7):

In the Expressive update dupes gain a +3 morale bonus from having a shower.